# Crossing the Canada-US border by car - documents needed and filling in I-94W

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, canada, paperwork, i-94

I will be flying to Canada in a few days. I am an EU citizen so I do not need a visa. During my stay, I also plan to visit the US for a day. This will be done by crossing the border by car.

I understand that when crossing the border into the US, I will have to fill in the I-94W form. I found a [copy of the form](https://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/documents/%20I-94W%20English%20%2811-11%29%20FINAL%20%28reference%20only%29.pdf) online. As I don't plan to stay in the US overnight, what am I supposed to write under items 13 and 14 (address whilst in the US)? I could state the city and state but no specific address. Should I leave it blank? Will it cause any problems at the border?

Additionally, when crossing back into Canada, which immigration formalities do I have to go through? Do I need to fill in another form, pass an interview, or will they just check my passport and I-94W and let me back in?

Additionally, when crossing the border, which documents should I bring with me? Obviously my passport, but should I also bring my flight booking showing that I will be leaving Canada (e.g. to show the US immigration officers that I do not intend to stay)? Anything else?

Comment: The Visa Waiver Program is a program of the United Sates Government.  What do you mean that you are flying to Canada under that program?  Canada is not part of the United States.  You should specify what country you are a citizen of, and what visa (if any) you will have for entering Canada.

Comment: @AriBrodsky OP is almost certainly a VWP national and visa-exempt for Canada

Comment: @AriBrodsky Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I have edited my post. I am an EU citizen so I do not need a visa to enter Canada (only eTA) and I also do not need a visa to enter the US (because of VWP).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you have a valid ESTA (you don't need it though), you will, at most road crossings, either not get the form at all, or you will be given a pre-printed one.

If you don't have an ESTA, just write "day trip" in the address field.

When entering Canada, you will be processed again for entry, but it's usually more lax than at airports. If you do get an I-94W form entering the US, make sure the Canadian officer takes it.

As for documentation, you don't need proof of onward travel if entering by land.

**PRO TIP**: as you don't have an ESTA, you can nevertheless [**fill out the form here**](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/#/apply-document) up to one week in advance, and get a pre-printed one at the border. Costs the same.

Comment: I don't have an ESTA as I have never been to the US before, and I know I don't need one either so I am not going to apply for it and save myself a few bucks. Thank you for answering all my questions in a concise manner :)

Comment: @SomeOne, If you don't have an ESTA you'll fill out the I-94W form, if you have one you won't and they'll just print a receipt for you instead. In either case, however, they'll send you inside to secondary (most other cars will just be waved through at the primary inspection booth) where they'll take your picture and finger prints and charge you $6. Having the US$6 in cash when you get there will save you the uncertainty of whether they'll accept your payment cards. There's no need to have proof of return travel when entering the US at a land border.

Comment: @SomeOne See the link I provided

Comment: @Dennis Thanks for providing me with the information.

Comment: @Coke Thanks for the link, I will keep it in mind.